# Android draw9patch tool

Tags: android, nine-patch

I've faced a problem while creating 9patch drawable.

Drawable is a button with image in the center. I want to stretch everything but that centered image. Now, when I add two dots on the top border using draw9patch tool - one on the left, and one on the right of centered image - that image moves to the right. The wider stretchable area I make on the right, the closer image is to the center of drawable.

Why it's work that way?

EDIT: drawable uploaded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: see this 9patch]    you need to add two dots on top and two dots on left

Comment: I have whole left border selected. Two dots on the right and two on the left? Anyway, setting two dots on lefto of image and two on right of image didn't help.

Comment: Now see, the problem is with your drawable it has 60px from left to start of black area and 70px from end of back area to right of image.

Comment: OK, but why whole drawable is stretched that the right side of it runs out of the image? If I set two dots on both sides of image, why it's not stretching evenly?

Comment: The stretching is equal on both sides since you have more pixels on right side it appears to be running out